Hikari Pool is not shutdown after spring boot test execution with test container
I have a Postgres test container with a maximum of 100 connections. The test container is reused for different tests.
   @Bean
   @ServiceConnection
   @RestartScope
   public PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer() {
      return createpostgreSQLContainer( dockerImageName );
   }

The Hikari Pool has a maximum of 25 connections.
If I now run more than 4 Spring Boot test classes in a row, I see that a Hikari pool with 25 connections is created for each test class. However, these pools will no longer be closed also when the test is over. After more than 4 tests, all connections are used up and the tests fail because they can no longer acquire a connection.
How to solve the problem?
EDIT:
I once built an MRE that shows the problem. If you run them all TOGETHER in IDE(e.g. Intellij) or maven, you will see the error messages in the logs. The problem is that 2-3 Hikarki pools are opened with 55 connections. But the TestContainer can only open 100.
What I've found out so far is the following:

If you only do repository testing WITHOUT a RestController, then only one HikarkiPool will be created and reused for all tests.
As soon as you add a RestController, the Hikarki pool is no longer reused and multiple ones are created. Then the problem occurs.



can u limit the connection pool to 1 in test.yml file ?

Yes this is working and my current workaround, but would like to understand the problem and root cause

Different configurations, lead to different instances of the application (and there are a lot of things influencing this like @TestPropertySource, different @ContextConfiguration, "optimizations" at the @SpringBootTest level and more). The different instances are cached for performance (with  max of 32 by default). Reduce the differences in configuration will help with this and will also speed up your testing.

Did you look into the MRE? It's also crashing if you have same configuration.
Let me make a second MRE without RestController there you see it's just working same setup.

Please read my comment and let it work in. Your tests don't have the same configuration. I thas nothing to do with your rest controller but all with your classes (and potentially more in your real project) in your tests. You have 2 different permutations of those leading to your application being loaded twice, resulting in 2 pools (each one has a datasource).

Clear now thanks. Sorry I understood you first answer wrong

The problem is your tests.
@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@SpringBootTest( 
  classes = { 
    TestConfig.class, 
    SQLContainerConfiguration.class,
    TestWebConfig.class }, 
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ConnectionPoolIssueTest1 {

@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@SpringBootTest( 
  classes = { 
    TestConfig.class, 
    SQLContainerConfiguration.class }, 
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ConnectionPoolIssueTest2 {

@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@SpringBootTest( 
  classes = { 
    TestConfig.class, 
    SQLContainerConfiguration.class,
    TestWebConfig.class }, 
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ConnectionPoolIssueTest3 {

@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@SpringBootTest( 
  classes = { 
    TestConfig.class, 
    SQLContainerConfiguration.class }, 
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ConnectionPoolIssueTest4 {

@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@SpringBootTest( 
  classes = { 
    TestConfig.class, 
    SQLContainerConfiguration.class,
    TestWebConfig.class }, 
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ConnectionPoolIssueTest5 {

@ExtendWith( SpringExtension.class )
@SpringBootTest( 
  classes = { 
    TestConfig.class, 
    SQLContainerConfiguration.class,
    TestWebConfig.class }, 
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ConnectionPoolIssueTest6 {

As explained in the Spring Framework Reference Guide the testing support in Spring will use context caching. To determine a key there is quite a long list of things that influence it.

An ApplicationContext can be uniquely identified by the combination of configuration parameters that is used to load it. Consequently, the unique combination of configuration parameters is used to generate a key under which the context is cached. The TestContext framework uses the following configuration parameters to build the context cache key:
locations (from @ContextConfiguration)
classes (from @ContextConfiguration)
contextInitializerClasses (from @ContextConfiguration)
contextCustomizers (from ContextCustomizerFactory) – this includes @DynamicPropertySource methods as well as various features from Spring Boot’s testing support such as @MockBean and @SpyBean.
contextLoader (from @ContextConfiguration)
parent (from @ContextHierarchy)
activeProfiles (from @ActiveProfiles)
propertySourceDescriptors (from @TestPropertySource)
propertySourceProperties (from @TestPropertySource)
resourceBasePath (from @WebAppConfiguration)

In your test setup there are at least 2 different permutations of configuration. Due to differences in the classes one with 2 (TestConfig and SQLContainerConfiguration and one with 3  classes (TestConfig, SQLContainerConfigurationandTestWebConfig`). This will result in at least 2 different instances.
TIP: You don't need @ExtendWith nor @EnableAutoConfiguration that is only overhead.

Thanks for the explanation. Now I get what you mean with caching.
Let me check my real situation. Thanks that help me
I'am using different @TestPropertySource(  ) on the tests, that is my issue

I created a common Configuration for all tests, but same issue. I guess there are some edge cases, because I inherit some test cases from a parent class.
I enabled the statistics:
45005 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.cache.logStatistics -- Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@76600c90 size = 2, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 45, missCount = 2, failureCount = 0]
Can I somehow looking what the cache key is?

If the context is created it isn't the same config. You have a different configuration of settings either classes, different parent, propertysource, active profile, mocks oer what not. If there is a difference you will get a new context.

Yes thats clear so far, but I see no difference between my two tests classes.
Iam debugging into the MergedContextConfiguration and (expected the test class) the content looks complete equals. So iam looking to find the best way to figure out, why I get a new context. Maybe there is a trick :)

It isn't just the @Configuration everything (see answer and documentation) plays a role. So if there is some internal configuration or a different profile, initializer or what not it will start again. Depending on the version the ordering of the configuration classes is important as loading the "same" configuration but with classes in a different order led to loading the context again.

Ok debugged the hash code it's the contextCustomizers there are the SpringBootTest config also from the parent class.
Is there a chance or a property that to ignore all configs from the parent class?

No there isn't, everything is merged into one config in the end. So no there is no way to ignore it. Unless you start meddling with context hierarchies.

Ok thanks again
